# VBA Check cell values in two columns

Tags: vba

I am looking for a solution to the following Problem. 
I have a table with 2 columns and I need a macro to check if the rows that have same values in first column, also have the same values in another column and give an error message if not. 
For example,

```
   1. a 12
   2. b 1
   3. c 567
   4. a 12
   5. c 567
   6. c 567
   7. b 1
```

If for example in the 7. row the value in the second column is "2", then the error message will appear. 
Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Several ways: Put the values of 1st col in a dictionary, execute a `find`-statement, execute a simple loop over the data...

Comment: In addition put a concatenated value in the key of a dictionary, use the .exists, so you'd check for say `C_567` in fact this wont be allowed to add, so you could even just trap the error.  Have a go and come back with issues you may have.  Google VBA scripting.dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Use data validation as Custom based on Formula:,

```
=isnumber(match(<relative cell address of top cell>, $a:$a, 0))
```